# SAGA cannot load any grids

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, file-path

Whenever I try to use a SAGA processing tool in QGIS which requires loading a file, it fails to load the files. The log message says:

> Loading grid: [PATH] failed.

The tools I've attempted to use have been `Fill sinks` and `Mosaicking`.

Since some threads seem to suggest path issues could cause this, I have tried changing my working folder, having it in within a user folder as well as outside. The same issue has also occurred with temporary file paths. I have no spaces or non-alphabetical characters anywhere in my paths. Have also tried updating to the latest version of SAGA.

I have seen other people posting the same issue here and there but no effective solutions. Do you have any idea what I could do to amend this?

I'm on Windows 10, QGIS version 3.28.10, Saga versions 7.8.2 and 9.1.2.

Comment: Could you please take a screenshot of the dialogue box before processing?